# Substr from character until character php

Tags: php

My problem is how to get substring from character until character in php.

I have tried this :

```
<?php 
$str = "I love my family";
echo substr($str, 'm', strpos($str, 'y'));

?>
```

It shows following error:

```
Message: substr() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given
```

expected result is : my family

Comment: unless its homework (which is fine) its unlikely to be a real world example, which would really help you in getting a usable answer.

Comment: isn`t from character `m` to character `y` return `my`? is it from char to end what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along these lines :

```
$str = "I love my family"; $from_char = 'm'; $to_char = 'y';

//  Find position of the $from_char
    $from_pos = strpos( $str, $from_char );

//  Now find position of blank space after $from_pos
    $blank_space_pos = strpos( $str, ' ',  $from_pos );

//  Find position of $to_char after $blank_space_pos
    $to_pos = strpos( $str, $to_char, $blank_space_pos );

//  Using $from_pos and $to_pos , get the substring
    echo substr( $str, $from_pos, $to_pos-$from_pos+1 );
```

Or something along these :

```
$str = "I love my family"; $from_char = 'm'; $to_char = 'y';

$from_pos = strpos( $str, $from_char ); // strpos finds first occurrence

$to_pos = strrpos( $str, $to_char ); // strrpos finds last occurrence

echo substr( $str, $from_pos, ( $to_pos-$from_pos+1 ) );
```

Both output :

> my family

Answer (score 2):

if you are not particular with using `substr` `strstr` can do the job.

```
$str = "I love my family";
echo strstr($str, 'm'); // my family
echo strstr($str, 'm', true); // I love
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php

Answer (score 1):

To get everything from "m" onwards, you can use [`strstr()`](http://php.net/strstr):

```
echo strstr('i love my family', 'm'); // my family
```

The example you gave isn't very good, because the string between "m" and "y" (inclusive) is "my". That aside, you can use `strpos()` to find the range:

```
$str = 'i love my family';
if (($start = strpos($str, 'm')) !== false && ($stop = strpos($str, 'y', $start)) !== false) {
    echo substr($str, $start, $stop - $start + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Corrected code:

```
<?php 
$str = "I love my family";
$pos = strpos($str, ' m');
echo substr($str, $pos);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

used this code:

```
<?php 
$str = "I love my family";
echo substr($str, strpos($str, 'm') , strpos($str, 'y')+1);
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Second parameter of substr() must not be string. It should be integer. [See this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php).
So you have to write something like

```
   echo substr($str, strpos($str, 'm'), strpos($str, 'y') - strpos($str, 'm') + 1);
```

(because third parameter is length, not position)

But this is not solution too, because you have 'y' not only at the end of the string (first 'y' is in word 'my', so this code returns only 'my'). So it is better to have another creteria of output string (not from 'm' to 'y', but from 'm' to end of line, for example `echo substr($str, strpos($str, 'm'));`)